# как найти позицию числа в массиве Javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы

```
var massiv = [4; 5; 7; 3; 8; 2; 2; 2; 5; 9]
```

как найти позицию первого вхождения числа '2' ?

Comment: `massiv.indexOf(2);` ну и в массиве значения через запятую должны быть

Comment: оперативно) спс

Answer (score 2):

Решение:

```
massiv.indexOf(2) // вернет index
```

Подробней про `indexOf` можно ознакомится на сайте:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf